# Output Custom CSS Settings in PHP

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to output some CSS i the head of my page with custom settings from my theme  customizer. The code below works great when there is a value but the problem is when there is no value, it still outputs everything else. I would only like it to appear if there are custom settings.

```
<style>
    body {background-color: <?php echo $background_color; ?>;}
</style>
```

I think it needs some kind of conditional statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `get_theme_mod`, which allows for a default setting. Since there's always going to be at least a default setting, there's no need for conditional statements to omit `style`, `body`, `background-image`, etc.

```
<style type="text/css">
    body { background-image: url("<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'background_image' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default.jpg' ); ?>"); }
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap conditionals around the declaration if necessary... For example:

```
<style>
    body {
      <?php if(!empty($background_color)) : ?>
      background-color: <?php echo $background_color; ?>;
      <?php endif; ?>
    }
</style>
```

If `background-color` will always be present, and you're looking to allow the background color to be overridden, you could do something like this:

```
<style>
    body {
      background-color: <?php echo !empty($background_color) ? $background_color : '#fff'; ?>;
    }
</style>
```

In this example, the background color will default to `#fff`. This method is known as the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: You want to move the conditional above everything and bail out if there is no background color to be rendered.  Why echo out an empty inline <style> and body declaration block if it's not doing anything?

Comment: This would do it, but I'm going to have a lot of custom settings and end up with a lot of if statements. I wonder is there a shorter way of outputting each css line only if there's a value?

Comment: @hellofromTonya True - though there's probably 4-5 other solutions that can apply - I felt it's best to provide the most accurate answer to this specific question though, or at least help provoke ideas so that the OP can formulate an idea. One such as an OOP solution.

Comment: @TroyTempleman if that's the case, you may want to consider creating a `collection` class of sorts... something that's more dynamic than this.

Comment: @HalfCrazed Yup, there are always multiple ways to solve the exact same problem.  My point was just to move the conditional up and wrap the script tag to avoid an empty CSS declaration block that doesn't do anything when there's no background color.  Else, it's just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to only render something out to the browser IF there's a background-color available.

This approach only renders out the inline script IF there's a background-color.  This technique avoids an empty CSS declaration in the DOM.

```
<?php if ( $background_color ) : ?>
<script>
    body {
        background-color: <?php esc_html_e( $background_color ); ?>;
    }
</script>   
<?php endif; ?>
```

### A Full Solution

Another way to handle it is to use `wp_add_inline_style()` and let WordPress handle it.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'build_and_enqueue_dynamic_css' );
/**
 * Build and enqueue dynamic inline head CSS.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function build_and_enqueue_dynamic_css() {

    // do the business logic to get the styles
    $background_color = ''; //you need to write this code.

    // Now check if you have a background color. If no, bail out.
    if ( ! $background_color ) {
        return;
    }

    $css =
"body {
    background-color: {$background_color};
}";


    wp_add_inline_style( 'your_theme_name_inline_css', $css );
}
```

Comment: Very thorough @hellofromTonya but trying to make this as compact as possible because I'm going to end up with many custom settings :)

Comment: So if you have more styles that could be rendered in the same file, then I'd advise using @HalfCrazed's solution.  You can repeat the pattern to load only what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more like what I'm looking for, but now I need a default color for background_color, before there's one input.

```
<?php self::generate_css( 'body', 'background-color', 'background_color' ); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like:

```
<style>
    body {
    <?php echo (!empty($background_color)) ? "background-color: " . $background_color.";" : ""; 
    ?>
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Why echo nothing?